# The website tomahawk-player.org maybe has an expired certificate. Should I ignore that?

Tags: macos, privacy, websites

I have an iMac running High Sierra 10.13.6. I wanted to download the Tomahawk music player from the developer site at www.tomahawk-player.org. Safari tells me the connection is not private. It appears their certificate expired 99 days ago. This seems like a long time for that to go on without the owners of the website upgrading their certificate. I just want to know if I should ignore this warning. I'm very hesitant to go there.

Comment: Doesn't give the greatest confidence if the site holders haven't even noticed after 3 months. I'd avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to sources that project has been "essentially abandoned" (nobody is working on it)

So, even if you download it, you are on your own with any problems that might occur.

As for accessing websites with expired certificate, you have been warned not to proceed, but you can at your own risk, witch could be major or minimal.

If you wish to proceed you can download the player from [here](https://github.com/tomahawk-player/tomahawk)

Just tried that and it Opens fine on HighSierra

Comment: I thought Tomahawk was the "latest and greatest". If the project has been abandoned I think I'll stay away. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @jmh not necessarily, The current version works. Once it stops working you can trow it away. You know the .org and free means someone has to pay for it, so they might just lost the sponsor.